# What's the best procedure enable / disable receiving gcm notifications?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to implement gcm into my app and show the user once a dialog on startup with the question if he wants to receive notifications.

The procedure I am thinking to do:

```
AlertDialog question -> yes or no
Store answer in SharedPreferences
if(true) { register procedure etc }
rest of code
```

Is this the way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a preference item to allow users to change their mind whenever they want. Moreover showing a dialog at startup will get your app startup bloated and boring. It should start and be usable ASAP.

Comment: So do both : a dialog if you want to, and a preference item. Also apps should have a EULA, so this makes 2 dialogs... quite a lot, no ? I don't consider GCM notifications are worth a dialog if it's easy to stop.

Answer (score 1):

yes that s how it should be implemented , and if the user want to get unregistred from push service , you should simply call : GCMRegistrar.unregister(context)